# bcrypt error: Devise ruby 2.0 and rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems, bcrypt

I keep getting this error when i try to run my app:

C:/ruby-2.0.0-p195-i386-mingw32/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0.rc1
/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require': cannot load such file -- 2
.0/bcrypt_ext (LoadError)

Any takers? - im trying to use the devise gem for basic user authentication..

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the bcrypt-ruby gem?

Comment: Have the same issue with the same setup.

Answer (score 26):

I've gotten this error when I updated to Ruby 2.0.0+ on Windows. I was able to solve it by uninstalling **all versions of bcrypt** that were downloaded, and building the gem using DevKit.

```
gem uninstall bcrypt-ruby

gem install bcrypt-ruby --platform=ruby --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

Usually doing a `bundle update` will download a precompiled gem `mingw32` extension, which in this case appears not to work. This workaround for reinstalling bcrypt-ruby will hopefully not be needed in the future.

Additionally, I keep updated Windows installation instructions for Ruby on Rails here (mostly for my own reference) for installing Ruby on Rails on Windows.

https://github.com/remomueller/documentation/tree/master/windows

Some other Windows pitfalls you may run into are also listed there:

https://github.com/remomueller/documentation/blob/master/windows/190-miscellaneous.md

Comment: This works however it will get overriden when you do a `bundle install`. I solved it by installing it from github.

Comment: Thanks Remo, I had to bundle install, then remove the bcrypt gem and install as per your instructions.

Comment: sometimes it is necessary to get bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1 - just execute `gem install bcrypt-ruby -v 3.0.1 --platform=ruby --no-ri --no-rdoc`

Comment: BTW: it is sufficient to `gem uninstall bcrypt-ruby` and select **-x86-mingw32** version to uninstall.

Comment: It still works only `bcrypt-ruby` changed its name to `bcrypt`. I'm so happy it still works.

Comment: It's taken me a week to solve this bcrypt problem by just following this. I did uninstall, reinstalled again, but I had gem bcrypt 3.1.17 added in the gemfile before doing the above process (@remos process). I didn't run bundle install.

Answer (score 9):

Until this problem is fixed, the best workaround is to install `bcrypt-ruby` from git:

```
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', git: 'https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby.git', :require => 'bcrypt'
```

**Update (June 2016.)** - [as @gneri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945291/bcrypt-error-devise-ruby-2-0-and-rails-4-0#comment52211632_17368137) mentioned, `bcrypt-ruby` changed it's name to `bcrypt`, so use:

```
gem 'bcrypt', git: 'https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby.git', :require => 'bcrypt'
```

Answer (score 2):

On problem with `has_secure_password` on Window 7 helps this

`gem uninstall bcrypt-ruby`

`gem uninstall bcrypt`

`gem install bcrypt-ruby --platform=ruby --no-ri --no-rdoc`

`gem install bcrypt --platform=ruby --no-ri --no-rdoc`

Add to Gemfile:

```
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0', :require => 'bcrypt'
gem 'bcrypt'
```

`bundle install`

Answer (score 0):

turns out that it was a problem with the version of ruby that i was using. I was using ruby 2 (32bit).

but if you switch to the 64bit version of ruby 2 the error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the downfall of using windows as a development platform for ROR apps. I need to use Ruby 2.0 32 bit in order to get PG gem for a postgresql connection to work or I have to use Ruby 2.0 64 bit to get 'Devise' gem to work.

Comment: I never had that problem; I've used Rails 4 as early as the first beta and never had to switch between 32-bit/64-bit of Ruby on Windows for either gem to work...

Comment: And it happens on Ubuntu, as well :\

Answer (score 0):

The new version of bundler just came out. It nows about x64 gems

```
gem install bundler -v '1.4.0.pre.2'
```