# block in replace_gem can't activate bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0.0), already activated bcrypt-ruby-3.1.1

Tags: bundle, bcrypt, bcrypt-ruby

I've looked at several answers regarding this problem and none seem to do the trick.  This is on windows and I am lost for ideas.  Thanks for the help!

C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1-x86-mingw32/lib/bcrypt_ext.rb:2:in `require': cannot load such fil
e -- 2.0/bcrypt_ext (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1-x86-mingw32/lib/bcrypt_ext.rb:2:in`'

```
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1-x86-mingw32/lib/bcrypt.rb:12:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1-x86-mingw32/lib/bcrypt.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require
```

'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in`block in require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in`require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
        from C:/Users/Natecraft/Documents/railstut/Nate_Enddy_d3/blog/config/application.rb:12:in`'
        from C:/Users/Natecraft/Documents/railstut/Nate_Enddy_d3/blog/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
        from C:/Users/Natecraft/Documents/railstut/Nate_Enddy_d3/blog/config/environment.rb:2:in`'
        from C:/Users/Natecraft/Documents/railstut/Nate_Enddy_d3/blog/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `require'
        from C:/Users/Natecraft/Documents/railstut/Nate_Enddy_d3/blog/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in`'
        from C:/Users/Natecraft/Documents/railstut/Nate_Enddy_d3/blog/spec/models/user_spec.rb:1:in `require'
        from C:/Users/Natecraft/Documents/railstut/Nate_Enddy_d3/blog/spec/models/user_spec.rb:1:in`'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in`block in load
_spec_files'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in`load_spec_fil
es'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.3/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in`run'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.14.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'

Comment: Looks similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17741040/cant-activate-bcrypt-ruby-3-0-0-already-activated-bcrypt-ruby-3-1-1-make

Comment: I've tried everything in that thread and nothing seems to work =/

Comment: You have the same error with bcrypt 3.0.0 in Gemfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved the same problem on my project.

The problem is that in version 3.1.1 the method 'has_secure_password' is not supported, so calling it in your model while in version 3.1.1 will not work.
However, as mentioned here -> [bcrypt error: Devise ruby 2.0 and rails 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945291/bcrypt-error-devise-ruby-2-0-and-rails-4-0), simply specifying a version in the gemfile won't work, because a windows compatible version will be used, which causes it's own issues.

My solution was to fork the bcrypt-ruby's github repo, then roll it back to 3.0.1 version and use that as the source for the gem, like this:

```
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', git: 'git@github.com:hananamar/bcrypt-ruby.git', :require => 'bcrypt'
```

You're invited to use my repo :)

Hopefully these issues will be fixed soon.