# BCrypt 3.1.2 update causing Heroku push to fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Developing on x64 Windows 7 machine, Ruby 2.0, Rails 4.0.0.
To utilize has_password functionality, I needed to install BCrypt.  Rails 4.0.0 supports BCrypt 3.0.0-3.0.9.  However, those versions of BCrypt do not work on a x64 Windows machine and I had to update to BCrypt 3.1.2.
But, I also had to manually update the ..\activemodel-4.0.0\lib\active_model\secure_password.rb to reference bcrypt 3.1.2 (previously referenced ~>3.0.0)

```
    begin
        gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.0'#changed from '~> 3.0.0'
        require 'bcrypt'
        rescue LoadError
              $stderr.puts "You don't have bcrypt-ruby installed in your application. Please add it to your Gemfile and run bundle install"
    raise
    end
```

Now my application and tests run locally.  I made this change due to the answers on [Issues using bcrypt 3.0.1 with ruby2.0 on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541062/issues-using-bcrypt-3-0-1-with-ruby2-0-on-windows)

However, now when I push to heroku, I get the following trace:

```
    -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   You don't have bcrypt-ruby installed in your application. Please add it to your Gemfile and run bundle install
   rake aborted!
   can't activate bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0.0), already activated bcrypt-ruby-3.1.
2. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.
.
.
.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/Rails app
```

I don't know how to get my app to run locally and on heroku with these changes.  I'm not sure if I need to push to heroku a different way, or if I need to address the bcrypt issue a different way.  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Not that the last version of bcrypt supported my rails at this moment (4.0.0) is the version 3.0.1.

If you try a version higher that, you will get the error.

Regards
PS

Comment: This answer doesn't make much sense, and doesn't seem right. I have this same problem, but I'm using bcrypt 3.0.1. I'm also on rails 4.0.3, but suspect this might be a heroky problem. Everything was fine using this bcrypt version on rails 4.0.0, now it's suddenly broken.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this by updating from `bcrypt-ruby` 3.0.1 to 3.1.5.

Comment: Important to note that both bcrypt and bcrypt-ruby have updates and errors on this, ensure you update both ideally. Happened now due to move to newer Heroku stack with an old application.